# Dark comedy about a doppleganger spirit/entity

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie within the last 5 years, at least 2 years ago. Based on film quality, I believe it was released between 2010 and 2015. It only had US actors.

It was a fairly low-budget film, but quite well made. Definitely an indie film.

A husband and wife have a struggling marriage, and rent a house for a vacation to try to rekindle their marriage. The house is large and nice, and there is a large guest house in the backyard.

Early on, some entity begins impersonating the wife, and sleeps with the husband. Not long after, it impersonates the husband and sleeps with the wife. At this point the entity appears as the spouse of whoever goes in the guest house, only as an idealized version of that person.

The couple quickly figures out what is going on. The wife wants to continue spending time with the doppelganger, but the husband is a bit jealous and concerned by the entity. I don't remember exactly how it ends, but the entity tries to fully replace the husband so that it can leave the property with the wife.

That's basically all I can remember. I don't think there's a single actor in the film other than these two, and I didn't recognize either at the time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the plot of the American indie thriller [The One I Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_I_Love_(film)) from 2014.

> **Confronted with the potential end of their marriage, Ethan (Mark Duplass) and Sophie (Elisabeth Moss)** are seeing a therapist (Ted Danson) regularly. After asking them to each play a note on a piano, he identifies a disconnection in their relationship and suggests they **take a weekend retreat to a large, secluded estate. The couple decides to try anything to save their marriage and agree to go.**
>
> Once at the estate, Ethan and Sophie make themselves comfortable, smoking some marijuana to relax. **Sophie goes to the guest cottage and, while there, has sex with Ethan.** Sophie returns to the house to find Ethan asleep. When she mentions the sex they just had, **Ethan claims he cannot remember the event**, so Sophie, annoyed that Ethan could ruin an otherwise romantic evening with a poor joke, goes to bed alone. Ethan, instead, curls up in the guest cottage. During the night, Sophie joins him in remorse, apologizing for her behavior and falling asleep next to him. [...] **Ethan quickly derives that something unusual is going on: when in the guest house cottage, each of them met a doppelgänger of the other, one who was convincing enough to pass without suspicion.**

Here's the trailer: